# Does deleting 'M'odified line in SVN Commit have an effect

Tags: svn, unix, vim, command-line

When running the command`svn ci` you get a text editor that allows you to place a comment, below that is there is the text "--This line, and those below, will be ignored--", then the files modified, added, or deleted.

If I were to delete a line such as:

`M folderA/fileA`

Would it remove that file from the check in, or is that just an SVN comment that has no other effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a comment, intended to show the changes that will be committed.

If you don't want to commit all changed/added/deleted files, you need to give it a list of the files that should be committed

```
svn ci file1 file2 dir1/
```

Answer (score 5):

I promise I'm not being sarcastic, but what will happen is

> This line, and those below, will be ignored

(it won't affect your commit)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well the file list is there as an aid to remember what you are checking in as you write the comment.
If you modify anything under the --ignore-- line, it will have no effect :)

Answer (score 1):

Removing that line will have no effect. If you want to commit only certain files, use

```
svn ci file1 file2 file3
```

instead of

```
svn ci
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a comment that has no effect, unlike other version control systems.

Answer (score 0):

Matt's answer is perfectly correct. The reason svn does this is so you can refer to the list of files being committed while composing the comment. It's intended to jog you memory about exactly what changes are being included.